# Is there a way to generate cypress report excluding failed test cases?

Tags: typescript, selenium, cypress, ui-automation, jira-xray

I hope all of you are doing good. As, the question states currently I am looking for a way to exclude failed test cases from Cypress xml report. I am using Junit as a reporter. The reason behind this is I am importing test results to Jira and whenever a test case fails it creates a duplicated test in jira instead of updating the test result. I will really appreciate if someone can help me with this. Looking forward to your answers. Thank you

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [junit-processor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-processor) utility that I've built, to postprocess the report :)

`junit-processor -e -f junit-xml`

And then upload that one instead.